# The option to select whether to connect a USB drive to Host Machine or Virtual Machine upon plugging in gone

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, vmware, workstation

I used to be able to select whether to connect a USB storage device (HDD or USB drive) to my host machine or virtual machine but the popup doesn't come up now. And now I am unable to connect my HDD or USB drive to my virtual machine as it automatically connects to the host machine once I plug in the device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the feature of remembering a connection rule for a specific USB device? Otherwise when you plug the USB device into the host system, Workstation Pro is supposed to prompt you to select a machine to connect the device to.

A connection rule is remembered when you select Remember my choice and do not ask again, and stays remembered until you configure Workstation Pro to forget the rule.

***Select the Machine a USB Device Connects To***
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-06E14969-21F2-4AB1-9E48-1974C28894BE.html